# Date extraction from file name in bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I am having a directory which contains multiple files with name in pattern abc12gddmmyyyy.zip.
I am working in bash script and I want to extract the pattern ddmmyyyy from the file name. Could anyone please help. I am new to linux enviornment. Thanks

```
Sample code

for filename in data/*; do
    date=<This part needed>
    echo $date
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, many solutions. One way could be to use `sed`:

```
date="$(echo "$filename" | sed -r 's/^.*12g([0-9]{8})\.zip/\1/')"
```

Comment: Using backticks \` is discouraged and using `$(...)` is [greatly prefered](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: This might fail with funny filenames with newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and a regex:

```
[[ "$filename" =~ (.{8})\.zip$ ]] && date="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

files:

```
ls ./files/
abc12g01022020.zip  abc12g02022020.zip
```

script:

```
for file in ./files/*
do
  echo $file | awk -F'.zip' '{print $1}' | tail -c 9
done
```

output:

```
01022020
02022020
```

Though to be honest it's a bit of a one-use-case scenario you've painted for us.

Comment: This might fail with funny filenames that have new-line characters.

Comment: Only if you escape it:
echo "abc12g\n02022020.zip"
> abc12g\n02022020.zip
echo -e "abc12g\n02022020.zip"
> abc12g
> 02022020.zip

Answer (score 0):

Here is another pure bash option:

```
for filename in data/*.zip; do
    date="${filename: -12:8}"
    echo "$date"
done
```

This method assumes that all your files have exactly the pattern as you describe: `<random_string>DDMMYYYY.zip`. Since the date is starting at the 12th character from the back, we can extract it as a substring.

> **`${parameter:offset:length}`** Substring  Expansion.   Expands  to  up  to `length` characters of
>                 parameter starting at the character  specified  by  `offset`. <snip> If `offset` evaluates to a number less than zero, the value  is  used
>                 as  an offset from the end of the value of parameter. <snip>
>                 A negative offset is taken relative to one greater than the max‐
>                 imum  index of the specified array. <snip>  Note that a
>                 negative offset must be separated from the colon by at least one
>                 space to avoid being confused with the `:-` expansion.
>
> **<sub>source: `man bash`</sub>**

**note:** be aware that a date-format of the type `DDMMYYYY` is not sortable and generally will lead one day to a lot of annoyance. It is always useful to use sortable formats like `YYYYMMDD`